# Passing data from view to controller in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, parameter-passing, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

i want to pass arguments from a blade view to a function in the controller

index.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('like', [$post->id, 1])  ) }}" class="like">
    Like
</a>

<a href="{{ route('like', [$post->id, -1])  ) }}" class="like">
    Dislike
</a>
```

PostController.php

```
  public function getLikePost($post_id, $like_value)
    {
       $post = Post::find($post_id);
       ...
    }
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('like', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@getLikePost',
        'as'   => 'like'
      ]);
```

but i get an error message

```
ErrorException in PostController.php line 149:
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\PostController::getLikePost()
```

could anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your route should be as:

```
Route::get('like/{psot_id}/{like_value}', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@getLikePost',
        'as'   => 'like'
```

And in your view:

```
<a href="{{ route('like', ['post_id' => $post->id, 'like_value' => 1]) }}" class="like">
    Like
</a>

<a href="{{ route('like', ['post_id' => $post->id, 'like_value' => -1]) }}" class="like">
    Dislike
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Route.php

```
Route::get('like/{post_id}/{like_value}', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@getLikePost',
        'as'   => 'like'
      ]);
```

> index.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('like', ['post_id' => $post->id, 'like_value' => 1]) }}" class="like">
    Like
</a>

<a href="{{ route('like', ['post_id' => $post->id, 'like_value' => -1]) }}" class="like">
    Dislike
</a>
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#required-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize $post_id and $like_value by empty value as like below.

**PostController.php**

```
public function getLikePost($post_id = '', $like_value='')
    {
       $post = Post::find($post_id);
       ...
    }
```